# Ansible- start multiple custom processes with overriding variables (same name) on same host (different group)?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

**S**o,
We have a scenario, where we need the ability to execute a custom command on a single or multiple hosts from a group with various possible values of the same variable.

For example-

```
#Inventory:
[ServerGroup_1]
abc0001 node=node1
abc0002 node=node2

[ServerGroup_2]
abc0001 node=node3
abc0002 node=node4

[ServersGroups: children]
ServerGroup_1
ServerGroup_2

group_vars/ServerGroup_1
JAVA_HOME: /home/java
PORT: 9998

group_vars/ServerGroup_2
JAVA_HOME: /home/java
PORT: 9999
```

The goal is to execute below shell command on host abc0001 with Ports as 9998 and 9999 within a single playbook run.

```
shell: {{ JAVA_HOME }} -Dprocess.port={{ PORT }}
```

Currently every time as per Ansible default variable behavior it is only getting executed for port 9999. Now, as an alternative, we could manually separate out the tasks and call it twice inside our playbook as explained [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/966019/ansible-same-host-on-different-groups-with-group-vars)

But, if we have 50 different ports that would be tedious to write and also we would want the configuration in such a way that it dynamically picks up from either inventory file or variable files, so for adding any new instance or running the command on different port, we just have to add it to our inventory/variable files rather than writing a separate task covering the port. The end configuration should work for all possible scenarios of running that command on one host of a group or all hosts from a group or a particular host and node combination....

```
ansible-playbook -i staging test_multinode.yml --limit=ServersGroups -l abc0001
```

The above playbook run should execute the shell command for both the ports 9998 and 9999 on abc0001 and the playbook needs to be flexible enough if just want to say start the process only for port 9998 on abc0001.

Note:
We have tried the with_items block by setting a Port variable in inventory file for the host, but that set up is very rigid and will not work for other scenarios.
We have also tried hash_behavior=merge and hash_behavior=replace settings in ansible.cfg, did not notice any change.

Hope this makes sense and We have not over-complicated things! Please suggest few options!!!

Comment: Fix the syntax `[ServersGroups:children]`. There shall be no space after colon ":"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Detailed Resolution](https://learnofy.org/ansible-how-to-use-alias-to-override-variables-for-same-hostname/)

> Short Answer- Rewrite the inventory file using aliases

```
 #Inventory:
[ServerGroup_1]
#variable with name PORT on host abc0001 from group1
group1_node1 ansible_host=abc0001 PORT=9998
group1_node2 ansible_host=abc0002 PORT=9999

[ServerGroup_2]
#same variable name Port on the same host abc0001 present in a different group
group2_node1 ansible_host=abc0001 PORT=9998
group2_node2 ansible_host=abc0002 PORT=9999

[ServersGroups: children]
ServerGroup_1
ServerGroup_2
```

We are using group1_node1 as an alias, so by doing this Ansible will register group1_node1 and group2_node1 as two different hosts even though it’s the same host abc0001.

Now, we will be able to start two processes on the same host abc0001 using different parameters for the same variable name PORT.

```
ansible-playbook -i staging test_multinode.yml --limit=ServersGroups -l group1_node1:group2_node1
```

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Execute a custom command on a single or multiple hosts from a group with various possible values of the same variable. Execute shell command on host abc0001 with Ports as 9998 and 9999 within a single playbook run.*"

A: Only dictionaries can be merged instead of default behavior replaced. See [DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour). Change the group_vars data to dictionaries. For example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/ServerGroup_1
my_sets:
  set1:
    JAVA_HOME: /home/java
    PORT: 9998

shell> cat group_vars/ServerGroup_2
my_sets:
  set2:
    JAVA_HOME: /home/java
    PORT: 9999
```

Then, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml
- hosts: ServersGroups
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value.JAVA_HOME }} -Dprocess.port={{ item.value.PORT }}"
      loop: "{{ my_sets|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge ansible-playbook -l abc0001 test.yml

ok: [abc0001] => (item=set1) => 
  msg: /home/java -Dprocess.port=9998
ok: [abc0001] => (item=set2) => 
  msg: /home/java -Dprocess.port=9999
```

---

> Q: *"We have also tried hash_behavior=merge and hash_behavior=replace settings in ansible.cfg, did not notice any change."*

A: The `replace` option works as expected. The same playbook gives

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=replace ansible-playbook -l abc0001 test.yml

ok: [abc0001] => (item=set2) => 
  msg: /home/java -Dprocess.port=9999
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. We tried another alternative which was to use aliases as described [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-aliases). So far this solution has been working file for all the given scenarios.

Comment: Post the details. I'd like to learn this alternative.

Comment: Based on your request, I have written a blog with detailed 
[solution](https://learnofy.org/ansible-how-to-use-alias-to-override-variables-for-same-hostname/). Please check it out. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Yes. It's helpful. Thank you. But, it's not "variables (same name) on same host (different group)" though. In other words, it's not a solution to the problem you posted here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not sure, if the article was not clear or there has been some misrepresentation on the problem I posted here. It's the solution to the problem I was trying to solve which was to start multiple processes on a node with different port variable values. In the modified inventory using alias, we are now able to use the" same variable name (PORT) on same host (abc001) which is part of multiple/different groups ServerGroup_1/ServerGroup_2 with multiple values as 9000 and 9001 without the PORT variable getting replaced or overridden."

Comment: Both the article is clear and the representation of the problem here is fine. The article deals with "same variables on different hosts" while the problem here is "same variables on the same hosts" (in different groups). These are 2 different problems. Why don't you post the "alternative" solution here when you think I'm wrong?

Comment: #Inventory:
    [ServerGroup_1] 
    group1_node1 ansible_host=abc0001 PORT=9000**(variable with name PORT      on host abc0001 from group1)**
    group1_node2 ansible_host=abc0002 PORT=9000

    [ServerGroup_2]
    group2_node1 ansible_host=abc0001 PORT=9001**(same variable same name    Port on the same host abc001 present in a differnt group)**
    group2_node2 ansible_host=abc0002 PORT=9001

    [ServersGroups: children]
    ServerGroup_1
    ServerGroup_2
    '

Comment: Post an answer, not a comment. This way you'll be sure it's clear and there is no misrepresentation.