# Ansible: merging of server vars from 2 groups not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Im using ansible 2.9.6 and I have a single server for now but it is within 2 groups in the host file. I have configured ufw for each group which has different firewall rules to apply, and when i run the playbook for 'db_servers' group its grabing the vars (ufw_rules) from the 'web_servers' group. Considering the server has the same name I would expect the vars to merge at least. but if i give the same servers a different name 'node_w' and 'node_d' in their groups, it will work with the corresponding vars for that group. I have no host_vars set to cause issues.

```
[web_servers]
node1 ansible_host=123.123.123.1

[db_servers]
node1 ansible_host=123.123.123.1

web_servers.yml
ufw_rules:
    - { service: http, port: 80, interface: '{{ ufw_default_public_interface }}', direction: '{{ ufw_service_default_direction }}', proto: tcp }
    - { service: https, port: 443, interface: '{{ ufw_default_public_interface }}', direction: '{{ ufw_service_default_direction }}', proto: tcp }

db_servers.yml
ufw_rules:
    - { service: mysql, port: 3306, interface: '{{ ufw_default_private_interface }}', direction: '{{ ufw_service_default_direction }}' }
```

Any ideas as to why its not getting the corresponding group vars, or at least not merging them both with the same name for server?

Comment: If you post the use-case [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'm sure there will be a solution without the requirement of merging the vars.

Comment: Let's see the use-case. Might be a duplicate of [Ansible- start multiple custom processes with overriding variables ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274503/ansible-start-multiple-custom-processes-with-overriding-variables-same-name-o/63275074#63275074)?

Comment: I actually don't expect the web_servers group ufw_rules to even be used, just the db_servers when running the playbook for db_servers, changing the same server in each group to different names solves it but it shouldn't right?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: "*Expect the vars to merge."*

A: See [DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour). For example

```sh
shell> ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

will merge **dictionaries**. Quoting:

> *"it does not affect variables whose values are scalars (integers, strings) or arrays"*

Comment: I have this set in the ansible.cfg file, so I'm still looking, I will try a mcve and post it